# Cascading Dropdown List Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, cascading, cascading-dropdown

i have 3 custom list. i Called it Area, Disiplin1 and WBS. for Area and Disiplin1 i set lookup to WBS column and i have create a script.

[image]

[image]

[image]

but if i try to create new item, the cascading is not correct. for example below. Supposedly when I select (area) E01, (Disiplin1) CI then WBS that appear is only E-01/1. is there something wrong with the script I created?
[image]